# How can I get my JavaScript carousel to work?

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I can't get my carousel working. As far as I can tell the code is right, maybe you can see the problem? Here's the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Randy's Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Ani.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class= "scene">
  <div class= "carousel">

    <div class= "cell">1</div>
    <div class= "cell">2</div>
    <div class= "cell">3</div>
    <div class= "cell">4</div>
    <div class= "cell">5</div>
    <div class= "cell">6</div>
    <div class= "cell">7</div>
    <div class= "cell">8</div>
    <div class= "cell">9</div>
    <div class= "cell">10</div>
    <div class= "cell">11</div>
    <div class= "cell">12</div>
    <div class= "cell">13</div>
    <div class= "cell">14</div>
    <div class= "cell">15</div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class= "carousel-options">
  <p>
    <label>
      Cells
      <input class= "cells-range" type= "range" min= "3" max= "15" value= "9" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class= "previous-button">Previous</button>
    <button class= "next-button">Next</button>
  </p>
   <p class= "pee">Orientation: </p>
      <label>
        <input type= "radio" name= "orientation" value= "horizontal" checked />
        Horizontal
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type= "radio" name= "orientation" value= "vertical" />
        Vertical
        </label>
      </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
var nextButton = document.querySelector(".next-button");
nextButton.aaddEventListener("click", function() {
  selectedIndex++;
  rotateCarousel();
});

var cellsRange = document.querySelector(".cells-range");
cellsRange.addEventListener("change", changeCarousel);
cellsRange.addEventListener("input", changeCarousel);

function changeCarousel() {
  cellCount = cellsRange.value;
  theta = 360 / cellCount;
  var cellSize = isHorizontal ? cellWidth : cellHeight;
  radius = Math.round(cellSize / 2 / Math.tan(Math.PI / cellCount));
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    if (i < cellCount) {
      //visible cell
      cell.style.opacity = 1;
      var cellAngle = thetaa * i;
      cell.style.transform =
        rotateFn + ")" + cellAngle + "deg) translateZ(" + radius + "px)";
    } else {
      // hidden cell
      cell.style.opacity = 0;
      cell.style.transform = "none";
    }
  }

  rotateCarousel();
}

var orientationRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="orientation"]');
(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < orientationRadios.length; i++) {
    var radio = orientationRadios[i];
    radio.addEventListener("change", onOrientationChange);
  }
})();

function onOrientationChange() {
  var checkedRadio = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="orientation"]:checked'
  );
  isHorizontal = checkedRadio.value == "horizontal";
  rotateFn = isHorizontal ? "rotateY" : "rotateX";
  changeCarousel();
}

//set initials
onOrientationChange();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The html and css work, i cant get the pictures to cycle through or the number of cells to change. so none of the javascript is working for some reason.
it keeps saying add more details even though i already have.

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it working? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: So everything looks right so I know the css and html are working, but the javascript does nothing... like when I click the next image button it does nothing, also when I click on the horizontal or vertical options it does nothing...

Comment: I'm in the process of learning Javascript. I found this on codepen and tried to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra `a` in one of your event listeners

Change:

```
nextButton.aaddEventListener( 'click', function() {
  selectedIndex++;
  rotateCarousel();
});
```

to

```
nextButton.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  selectedIndex++;
  rotateCarousel();
});
```